# Using escape character to combine commands in shell?

Tags: bash

I've seen strange usage of escape character in a bash script (the line with `unzip`):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "doing something"
unzip "${1}" || echo "Failed to unzip ${1}" \ exit 1
echo "doing something"
```

Escaping a space to combine commands?
Is unzip line equivalent to the following?

```sh
unzip "${1}" || (echo "Failed to unzip ${1}"; exit 1)
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is one way to preserve literal value of the character following it. See [Bash manual - 3.1.2.1 Escape Character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html)

So in your case, the `\` just escapes the space character. So basically, the `exit 1` is *not* run, but just concatenated as literal arguments to `echo` along with expanded value of `"Failed to unzip ${1}"` i.e.

```sh
echo 'Failed to unzip ' ' exit' 1
```

But the below case, runs the actual `exit 1` returning a exit code back to the parent shell after echoing the error from `unzip` because of the [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html), where each command in the group `(..)` separated by `;` are executed.

So the examples are not the same.

```sh
(echo "Failed to unzip ${1}"; exit 1)
```

A minimal example to recreate and understand the behavior is to do below and manually check the exit codes after running both i.e. doing `echo $?`

```sh
false || echo 'failure?' \ exit 1
failure?  exit 1
```

and

```sh
false || ( echo 'failure?';  exit 1 ; )
failure?
```

Comment: So seems the script author just mad a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I've performed tests you provided and read the links and now I understand how to fix that script. I will use `{ list }` instead of `( list )` for command grouping, otherwise current script does not exit with error code.